# Is it a good idea to mix ~ and ^ in package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, package.json

Apologies if the question is too generic, I can make it more specific if required, but want to understand the best practice here.

I am working on a monorepo where each project would have a different version of `jest`. In the `package.json` file, all `@types` are defined with `~` while other packages with `^` (I guess the rationale was that there are more breaking fixes are introduced in `@types` - not sure it is true). Therefore, I have,

```
"jest": "^29.0.3",
"@types/jest": "~29.0.3",
```

In the last few days, I am starting to get some strange issues with picking the right version of `jest` (even in the other monorepo directories). I also noticed that the latest `jest` version is now `29.2.0` while the latest `@types/jest` is `29.1.2` (this should not happen really, no?)

If I change both versions to, say `29.1.2`, the problem disappears.

My question, though, is it ok to have different scope definition (~ vs ^) in the corresponding `@types` and regular packages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version mismatches between types and JS packages are relatively normal and shouldn't cause any issues most of the time.